# DataTable merge without primary key column

Tags: c#, merge, datatable

How to merge tables in which destination table contains primary key column and source table doesnt contain. DataSet enforceConstraints is set to false then it will merge the table. but when execute GetChanges() on destination table exception occurs.

```
//Dest table contains primary key which is missing in source table

        DataSet ds;
        DataTable source;
        ds.EnforceConstraints = false;
        ds.Tables["Dest"].Merge(source,true,MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
        ds.Tables["Dest"].GetChanges();
```

Comment: Simplest solution: add a primary key to your source. To quote Joe Celko: *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried to merge tables without primary key.
I think its not possible.